# Replace character on uitextfield with image of character/number

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have some images number (0 ~ 9) in png. I use uitextfield and want to replace number i typed in uitextfield with this images. How can i achieve this with all uitextfield behavior (type character, delete when i tap backspace, etc) ?
Any other workaround can be accepted too.

Comment: What do these images look like? `UITextField` doesn't support anything but text. But you might be able to use some special Unicode characters for the numbers or use attributed text to change the appearance of the numbers.

Comment: i plan to use image like these (https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=number+1&revid=1899668103&dpr=1&biw=1920&bih=976). the names like '1.png', '2.png', '3.png' and so on.

Comment: Check this control: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/imgglyph

Comment: thanks. it's close to what i need, but i need to use uitextfield and its behavior